# Is there a way to reshape graphics in ArcEngine?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

Our GIS-tool should allow the customer to reshape self drawn (polygon) graphic elements, like one can  reshape features in edit mode with the [Editor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/EditorClass_Class/002000000019000000/).

Is it possible to reshape graphic elements?

If not, I think of turning the polygon graphics to features.

**Update:**

I would accept a simple 'No' :)